# Get pixel color of image

Tags: c++, gdi+

I want to get values of R, G and B of pixels of an image. I already did it with HDC, but now I would like to complete it with Gdi+ and input image.

This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "gdiplus.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace Gdiplus;
using namespace std;

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
Bitmap* mybitmap = new("bink.bmp");
int x=0;
int y=0;
Color pixelColor;
//Color pixelcolor[1000][1000];
for ( x = 0; x < 640; x++ )
   {
      for ( y = 0; y < 480; y++ )
      {
             //Color pixelColor[x][y] = mybitmap->GetPixel(x,y);
         mybitmap->GetPixel(x,y, &pixelColor);
         cout << "Pixel color " << x << ",  " << y; "is  " << pixelColor;
         //cout << "Pixel color " << x << ",  " << y; "is  " << pixelColor[x][y];
      }
   }
}
```

It is not working... can You help somehow?

Comment: what does it mean "it is not working"?

Comment: Are you sure about this `Bitmap* mybitmap = new("bink.bmp");` ?

Comment: "It's not working" is a bit vague. To me, this looks like it woukdn't even compile. Where do you get what error?

Comment: I am getting few errors, for example with operator "<<"  in cout. 
@Jigsore No I am not sure, I just thought it should be like this.

Comment: Try with `Bitmap* mybitmap = new Bitmap(L"bink.bmp");`. BTW, `cout` can't handle `Color` objects natively (check [Color methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534427%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#methods)).

Answer (score 0):

you should be using pixelColor.GetGreen, pixelColor.GetRed, pixelColor.GetBlue